# Semantic UI sidebar throws console errors with ReactJS when render app to body

Tags: meteor, reactjs, semantic-ui

Any way to render Semantic-UI sidebar into a React App without using id tags in HTML body? I want to avoid having to render React components to tagis within the HTML body like NOT using: `<div id="some-name"></div>`.

I'm using Meteor but shouldn't make a difference for this issue appears React & Semantic UI specific.

The code below gives the following errors in browser console:

```
Sidebar: Had to add pusher element. For optimal performance make sure body content is inside a pusherSidebar: 

Had to move sidebar. For optimal performance make sure sidebar and pusher are direct children of your body tag <div class=​"ui sidebar inverted vertical menu left uncover animating visible" data-reactid=​".0.0">​…​</div>​ 

Warning: ReactMount: Root element has been removed from its original container. New container:
```

**index.html**

  semantic-sidebar1

**app.js**

```
// App component - represents the whole app
App = React.createClass({

  showSideMenu() {
    $('.ui.sidebar')
      .sidebar('toggle');
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <div className="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
            <a className="item">
              1
            </a>
            <a className="item">
              2
            </a>
            <a className="item">
              3
            </a>
          </div>

        <div className="pusher">
          <button onClick={this.showSideMenu} className="ui button">Test MyModalDlgOne</button>

          <p />
          React App.
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code is executed on the client only

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // Use Meteor.startup to render the component after the page is ready
    // React.render(<App />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
    React.render(<App />, document.body);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I have some experience implementing a reactJS + Semantic-UI sidebar, so might be able to help.

The reason the errors are being thrown is that the Sidebar component adheres to the `<body>` tag by default, and will add a *pusher* class to an adjacent element to use as the window content to move/cover during animation.

I'm not fully sure what you want to do, but it looks like you want to initialize the sidebar so the `<body>` tag is the parent tag of the React render result, but keep the DOM structure you provided. Something like this:

```
<!-- Your desired parent element -->
<body>
    <!-- Return result of the React render -->
    <div>
        <div class="ui sidebar"></div>

        <div class="pusher"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This will work fine *if* you are planning on using the `<div class="pusher">` element as the context for the Semantic-UI. If this is the case, you need to define a context when you initialize the sidebar. You can initialize it in `showSideMenu()` but might be more appropriate in `componentDidMount()`.

```
   componentDidMount: function() {
       // Localize the selector instead of having jQuery search globally
       var rootNode = React.findDOMNode(this);

       // Initialize the sidebar
       $(rootNode).find('.ui.sidebar').sidebar({
           context: $(rootNode)
       });
   },
   showSideMenu: function() {
       // Same thing as before, might want to store this as a variable
       var rootNode = React.findDOMNode(this);
       $(rootNode).find('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
   }
```

This is documented in **[Using a custom context](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples)**.

Comment: The errors go away, but the contents in the pusher show over top of the sidebar, not underneath. Also, adding your code example in `showSideMenu()` makes no difference, i.e. only seem to need the code you wrote in `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: This on the main root `<div>` fixes the overlay issue mentioned above, `className="ui segment pushable"`.

Comment: OK, now I get it, it's faster to use .findDOMNode than start at the very top of the DOM tree when using jQuery. RE: your code example in showSideMenu() makes no difference.

Comment: There's a side effect, where the side menu now scrolls with the page content. And a `top fixed menu` that's rendered from a separate React component hides the top of the sidebar. Semantic has pretty strict rules about `<div>` tags being siblings, which React breaks when Semantic UI classes are nested inside a React component.

Comment: Also, clicking a link in the sidebar doesn't close the sidebar.

Comment: These are some separate problems. The clicking a link to close the sidebar is by design, and is up to you to implement with a link-click event handler.

If you would like to use an overlay transition instead of a push, you can specify it in the sidebar initialization settings along with context as another option - _transition: overlay_

Comment: The problem with the sidebar scrolling with page content and being covered with a fixed top header depends on how you'd like to lay out the page. If you'd like the sidebar to scroll independently of page content, it must have its own overflow CSS setting. The reason it is now scrolling with the page content means that it is taking the same size as the `<div>` element which is the React rootnode. Take a look at the source code for the [custom context](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples) example.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep working on this, and I'll create a test sidebar without React so I can see the default behaviour minus any side effects from console errors. As once I implemented your fix the behavior changed drastically.

Comment: @GiantElk Wondering if you've had any luck with this? i'm trying to implement something like this and am running into the same issue. - I've tried creting my own sidebar component using this guide (http://jamesknelson.com/rendering-react-components-to-the-document-body/) but I can't seem to figure out how to keep the sidebar's context after it has been rendered.

Comment: I haven't had time to re-visit this. It's on my todo list, just not sure when I'll get to it.

Comment: Thanks @J3Y, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the context setting of the sidebar. Let try the code below and let me know if it works!

```
<div id="application">
    <div class="ui sidebar"></div>
    <div class="pusher"></div>
</div>

jQuery('.ui.sidebar').sidebar({
    context: '#application'
});
```