# Using Semantic-UI's fixed menu and sidebar in React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use Semantic-UI's fixed menu and sidebar together with the React framework. I would like to achieve the same results as the Semantic-UI's Docs page (in Tablet and Mobile displays) with a fixed menu at the top and a left sidebar that is overlaid when toggled.

I have put together an example of that here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bullwinkle/m3hr5v36/

It works, but Semantic-UI doesn't like the layout, and provides the following errors in console:

```
Sidebar: Had to add pusher element. For optimal performance make sure body content is inside a pusher element
Sidebar: Had to move sidebar. For optimal performance make sure sidebar and pusher are direct children of your body tag <div class=​"ui inverted left vertical sidebar menu" data-reactid=​".0.0">​…​</div>​
```

So Semantic-UI moves the layout around so that `.sidebar` and `.pusher` are direct children of `<body>`. That's not exactly the React way.

As explained here:

[Semantic UI sidebar throws console errors with ReactJS when render app to body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495447/semantic-ui-sidebar-throws-console-errors-with-reactjs-when-render-app-to-body)

you would need to define a custom context for the sidebar. OK, so I've done that in the sidebar initialization:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar({
        transition: 'overlay',
        context: $('#layout')
    });
},
```

(see the 4th revision of the jsfiddle, I can't post more links because of low rep)

That fixes the error messages, but now the top menu is no longer fixed, and the sidebar scrolls along with the content. I've tried everything I can to get Semantic-UI and React to play along nicely, but I'm obviously missing something

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: same problem. still no solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ember, it generates the following DIVS:

```
<div data-label="layer-div" style="display: none;"></div>
<div data-label="preview-div" style="pointer-events: none; display: none;"></div>
```

... before your content, which creates problems for the sidebar, as the content needs to be wrapper in a PUSHER class so the sidebar can PUSH it over when it open.

So, React is adding some extra content outside of your pusher class, that's what it's complaining about.

```
{{!-- Pusher means that the sidebar will push it out of the way --}}
<div class="ui grid pusher">
```

If you have any content prior to your pusher class, with the exception of the sidebar div, you will get the error. Take a look at your source, you will see that Semantic-ui has created a second pusher class to wrap the content generated by react.